# Programming in Python using a Non-English language for keywords and variables

Tags: python, programming-languages

My end goal is to enable people that know the language Urdu and not English to be able to program in a Python environment.

Urdu is written left to right. I imagine having Urdu versions of all python keywords and using Urdu characters to define variable/function/class names.

Is  this goal possible? If yes, then what all will need to be done?

I can already see one issue where the standard library functions would still be in English.

**Update:**
Whether this *should be done* or not is certainly a very interesting debate topic, which I'd love to talk about. *However, is it actually possible and how?*

I love Python and I know a lot of intelligent people that might never be taught English properly, only Urdu, hence the thought.

Comment: Ummm, I hate to be English centric, but I'm afraid it is the lingua franca for all sorts of things (programming being one of them) - so sadly, as great as this idea is, I think you'd actually be hindering people, rather than making things better for them...

Comment: Sorry if this sounds a bit blunt, but that would make no sense, any kind of such balkanization would be detrimental to any kind of progress. English is easy, English used in programming languages is even easier, don't add complexity where there's no need for it.

Comment: In python3 you can use any unicode characters for variable names. To rename keywords, you'll have to rewrite python. Please don't do any of that!

Comment: I agree with @JonClements -- but if you insist, it probably wouldn't be too hard with a simple `re.sub`, providing a mapping of english keywords to Urdu equivalents as a simple pre-processor.

Comment: You can write a preprocessor that translates text into python code.

Comment: I would not be SO categoric. I guess that would be interesting for people who never programmed before, to first be able to understand the programming basics in a familiar language.
 If the goal is to have a actual, complete Urdu version of Python, then I agree it makes no sense.

Comment: Whether this *should* be done or not is certainly a very interesting debate topic, which I'd love to talk about. However, *is it actually possible and how?*

Comment: It's already possible to name all your variables using any unicode.  If you want to edit the Python standard library, it is open sourced, so feel free.  I advise against that, however.

Comment: @William Lets say I take the route of not modifying the language & standard library. Instead, I write a pre-processor to convert Urdu version of the code to english, would that be practically possible? i.e. to support urdu keywords and urdu function names for all standard library functions?

Comment: I guess, python itself is not the problem, but for a clean solution (not requiring a standard python installation in the background) you would have to transform the huge amount of standard libraries to your new variant, not to mention the help files... In the days of BASIC there was indeed a german adaption for the keywords. It read strange even for a native speaker, and never got a substiantial following. I guess you would be better off, to make a translation cheat sheet of python to Urdu as a starting point and ignite enough enthusiasm to translate the help.

Comment: If you are teaching five year olds to program, then it might be useful, although I doubt that. The words are so abstract that I'm not sure it would help to translate them. "för apa i apor" is not clearer than "for apa in apor", in fact, "för" kan mean a whole bunch of things, so I think it might be *less* clear.

Comment: Flip your screen horizontally :)

Comment: @MorganWilde is that what they said about ASCII too?

Comment: @Boris what's that got to do with ASCII? If you're implying that a move to Unicode is somehow similar to translating programming language keywords to other human languages – you're wrong.

Comment: @MorganWilde at least for Python, translating just the keywords would be trivial, at least from a technical standpoint. Making functions that have the same signatures and just pass stuff off to the original functions would also be a lot of manual but straightforward work. It's the error message strings that would be hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Chinese Python](http://www.chinesepython.org/) used to allow programmers to write source code entirely in Chinese, including translated module names, function names, and all keywords. Here's a code example from their website:

```
載入 系統               # import sys
文件名 = 系統.參數[1:]   # filenames = sys.argv[1:]

定義 修正行尾(文件):     # def fixline(file):
    內文 = 打開(文件).讀入()  # text = open(file).read()
    內文 = 內文.替換('\n\r','\n') # text = text.replace('\n\r', '\n')
    傳回 內文          # return text

取 文件 自 文件名:     # for file in filenames:
    寫 修正行尾(文件)  # print fixline(file)
```

Sadly, it is no longer an active project, but you can get the source and find out what they changed to get an idea for your own implementation. (Learning why they failed may also help you understand what challenges you will have in making such a system successful).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [ideas](https://aroberge.github.io/ideas/docs/html) project to transform keywords,
it has an [example](https://aroberge.github.io/ideas/docs/html/_modules/ideas/examples/french.html) for making a kind of French Python.

It's based on [python import-hook](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-hooks) so it runs in normal python3.

I built a [python in Hebrew](https://github.com/matan-h/hebrew-python) (that also uses the python builtins and not just keywords ) using this project ,that looks more like a normal python

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. But it requires you to download Python from source, and change the source code and compile it. If I remember correctly from another discussion on the same topic, changing the grammar and regenerating some files is all it takes, except for when you are doing advanced stuff like meta-programming and things.

Comment: If a computer language's is well designed so that keywords are defined in one place, you should just have to change them to what you want and recompile. I'm trying to design an assembly language with that in mind.

Comment: Yes, but there are more things in a Python distribution than the language. The standard library includes several parsers, for example. I'm pretty sure 2to3 will stop working, for example.

Answer (score 0):

WHAT HAVE YOU TRIED? Python 3 allows you to use Unicode for all your function, class and variable names. Check it out, you just need to make sure you're using utf-8 for your script-- it's primarily a matter for your editor. Dealing gracefully with the mixed RTL/LTR issues is also your editor's problem. (The feature is discussed in [PEP 3131](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131/))

The python language does not have "dialects", i.e., alternative sets of keywords. If you are not satisfied with Urdu identifiers and you are determined to have a completely Urdu-language experience, you could write a preprocessor that maps Urdu "keywords" to the corresponding (English) python keyword.

It shouldn't be too hard to wrap this kind of preprocessor around the interactive console and import modules, so that it works transparently to the user (and without recompiling python from source). If you can program and want to try this on for size, check out python's [`code`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/code.html) module. It's designed to read python source and send it on to be compiled and executed. You just step in and add a preprocessing step.

I'd use a preprocessor for keywords and built-ins. But providing localized wrappers for your choice of common modules is even easier, actually. Let's demonstrate with a wrapper module `RE.py` that contains all *exported* identifiers of regular `re`, but renamed to upper case:

```
import re as _re
for name in _re.__all__:
    locals()[name.upper()] = _re.__dict__[name]
```

That was it! You can now import this module and use it:

```
import RE
docs = RE.SUB(r"\bEnglish\b", r"Urdu", docs)
```

Use Urdu words instead of uppercase (of course you need to specify each one individually) and you're on your way. As you say, whether all this is a good idea is a different question.